# Проблема при создании магазина на фэйсбуке

Tags: facebook

Всем привет. При создании магазина на фб, нужно пройти пункты, где нужно отметить нужный и подходящий вариант для компании. и на 3ем пункте, где нужно "выбрать канал сбыта" идет список моих каналов-магазинов (компании с которыми я работаю) и есть тот самый нужный канал, с которого я и зашла в настройки Магазина, но не могу его выбрать, пишет "Вариант "Аккаунт Business Manager" нельзя выбрать, так как он не соответствует нашим требованиям к магазинам.". Перечитала все что только можно, требования никаких не нашла, либо они и так у меня есть.
Это магазин и я админ. Кто ни будь сталкивался с этим?

Comment: та же проблема и у меня, только магазин сначала создался, а потом все залагало и такая же ситуация.
Только для чего мне отвязывать инсту для создания магазина? как это вообще может быть связано, если я рекламируюсь со своего фп в фейсбуке и с инсты(от этого же фп) в инсте. Бред какой-то ,если честно, нихрена не понимаю

Answer (score 0):

Удалите привязку Instagram аккаунта к странице в Facebook. Это поможет

Comment: Не помогает
Та же ошибка осталась